# Migration from HDP to MapR

Tags: migration, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, mapr

I am bit new to MapR Hbase but I have worked with Hbase with HDP/Cloudera. We have hbase cluster in HDP and we are planning to migrate Hbase data to MapR Hbase cluster.

What should be appropriate approach that I can take here? (Downtime is not a problem for us at this moment.)

Should we use export/import utilities, copytable commands, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create the destination table by hand and then use the CopyTable command. For details, see

http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Migrating+Between+Apache+HBase+Tables+and+MapR+Tables